# wordpress show all custom taxonomies and their associate posts

Tags: wordpress

Is their any way in wordpress custom taxonomy to show all categories and associate their posts as well means:

```
my category1
post 1
post 2
post 3
post 4


my category2
post 1
post 2
post 3
post 4
```

note i have to do this in custom post type, taxonomy.

Comment: Is any one here to help me in this situation.

Comment: If someone can help, I offer +100 from my reputation.Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise? What exactly do you want to accomplish? You want to list all items of a taxonomy and all post items which are contained in this taxonomy below?

Why not using the standard wordpress taxonomy functions and nested Custom Queries?

Comment: Are "mycategory1" and "mycategory2" taxonomies, or taxonomy terms? (for example, 'Washington' could be a term in the taxonomy 'Cities')... Are they from the same post type? Could you give a specific example using the exact custom post type, taxonomies and a few example post titles that you want to use? That would help me to form a more helpful, meaningful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work, I haven't tested it thorough

```
$args = array (
    'type' => 'post', //your custom post type
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 0 //shows empty categories
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($categories as $category) {    
    echo $category->name;
    $post_by_cat = get_posts(array('cat' => $category->term_id));

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $post_by_cat as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

source:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

questions just ask